# updating a textfield based on radio button selection

Tags: php, html, ajax, yii, radio-button

I have some 25 radio buttons, such that only one selection can be done. On selecting a particular radio-button, an ajax update is to be performed on the risk grade textfield of this form. And, this textfield should get uniquely updated on every radio-button selection.

[image]

How's this possible. Please, I am really stuck here. 
I had done by normal radio button code for each one.
I used the ajax update as done in dependent dropdown textfield, but, I am not sure the same thing is appropriate here.
I think I am getting something wrong here. Any thing would be really helpful.

```
                   <table id="department_permissions_table" class="display">
                    <thead>
                    <tr style="background-color: lavender"><td style="background-color: white"></td><td><b>Effect</b></td>
                    <td></td><td></td>
                    <td></td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: lavender"><b>Likelihood of recurrence</b></td>
                        <td style="background-color: #f5f5f5"><b>Negligible</b></td>
                        <td style="background-color: #f5f5f5"><b>Minor</b></td>
                        <td style="background-color: #f5f5f5"><b>Moderate</b></td>
                        <td style="background-color: #f5f5f5"><b>Major</b></td>
                        <td style="background-color: #f5f5f5"><b>Catastrophic</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #f5f5f5"><b>Almost certain</b></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>11,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>12,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>13,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>14,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>15,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #f5f5f5"><b>Likely</b></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>21,
                                'uncheckValue'=>null,
                                'ajax' => array(
                                    'type'=>'POST',
                                    'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('Cinvestigation/load'),
                                    'update'=>'#risk_grade',
                                    'data'=>array('region_id'=>'js:this.value'),
                                )
                            )); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>22,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>23,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>24,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>25,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>

                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #f5f5f5"><b>Possible</b></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>31,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>32,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>33,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>34,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>35,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #f5f5f5"><b>Unlikely</b></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>41,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>42,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>43,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>44,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>45,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #f5f5f5"><b>Rare</b></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>51,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>52,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>53,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>54,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>55,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?></td>

                    </tr>



                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="span2" style="width:auto; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom: 5px">Grade risk: </div></td>
        <td><?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'risk_grade',array('class'=>'span2','maxlength'=>100)); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need ajax update for this task. You could easily do it with jQuery, you just need to have some kind of mapper for radio button values and string you want to set for the text field

First set the class for each radio button

```
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'a11',array('value'=>51,'uncheckValue'=>null, 'class'=>'radioClass')); ?>
```

Than set the class for textfield

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'risk_grade',array('class'=>'textClass span2','maxlength'=>100)); ?>
```

Then attach event listener in javascript

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".radioClass").click(function(){
            $(".textClass").val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

This code will but clicked radio button value into textfield's value

Now you may need some kind of mapper for radio button values and the text you want to display, which may be generated by the server side

I hope I helped